# Websphere & Tivoli: NPE while trying to create PDAuthorizationContext

Tags: websphere-8, tivoli

I am getting the following error when I try to start my Application...

> [java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.NullPointerException^M
>           at com.tivoli.pd.jutil.kb$1.run(kb$1.java:41)^M
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:229
>   )^M
>           at com.tivoli.pd.jutil.kb.c(kb.java:141)^M
>           at com.tivoli.pd.jutil.kb.(kb.java:56)^M
>           at com.tivoli.pd.jutil.PDContext.(PDContext.java:76)^M
>           at com.tivoli.pd.jazn.PDAuthorizationContext.(PDAuthorizationConte
>   xt.java:66)^M

I double checked the config file was accessible and I could read it. The code I am using looks as follows...

```
aC = new PDAuthorizationContext(cFile);
```

Is there a way to get more information on what is causing the NPE?

**More information!!!**

After debuging a bit, it appears the issue comes from this code (they use progaurd so it is a little hard to be 100% confident)...

```
Certificate[] arrayOfCertificate1 = ((KeyStore)???).getCertificateChain("DefaultID");
//Throws Null pointer (presumably because array is null)
Certificate localCertificate1 = arrayOfCertificate1[0];
```

**EVEN MORE INFO**

This appears to be some kind of dependency conflict (guess), because if I just create a sample App using PDAuthorizationContext it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was related to the PD.jar version that I was using. Although I thought I was using one version I was using another. This was because on version was registered in my WebSphere library (under build path in eclipse). Once the proper library was introduced everything worked.